# Suppose there is a chessboard with 64 squares (8x8)

Tags: geometry

and we cover the corner white squares leaving us with 62 squares. Can we conver the whole board with dominoes so that no two dominoes overlap?

I came to the conclusion no because each ending side of the board, the rows and columns on the outside have 7 squares and you can't fit dominoes into an odd number

Comment: You're correct that it isn't possible, but your reasoning won't prove it. For example, you could take out two squares in a corner leaving 6 rows of 8 and 2 rows of 7 and still cover it with dominoes.  Think about the coloring of the squares.

Answer (score 1):

Each domino must cover both a white and a black square. Thus the number of covered white squares equals the number of covered black squares in any arrangement of non-overlapping dominoes. As there are $32$ black and $30$ white in your situation, the covering you seek is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Since both removed squares have identical color, their removal leaves 30 white squares and 32 black squares. Since a domino always covers one black and one white squares, the 62 remaining squares cannot be filled with dominos.